# Is the Alcor AU6371 card reader supported in 12.10 64bit?

Tags: card-reader

I have now spend several evenings searching this forum for an answer on how to get the internal card reader on my desktop working.  It does not show up in any of the lists that terminal commands have produced and the various 'fixes' that I have been able to attempt have not worked.  A list of supported card readers has not been located, so purchasing an alternative may not work.  The Alcor data sheet for AU6371 B51-JDL-GR indicates that it should work without an external driver, but does not mention Linux.

Is there a solution?

Sorry for slow response to the assistance, I got locked out and had to have my account recovered!

I tried putting an SD 128MB card into the reader prior to boot, but not visible in Home Folder (Nautilus?).  I also tried an SDHC 32GB with the same result.

Input-utils is installed
Medibuntu is a listed source

Tried alternative usb connectors on the ASUS motherboard, with no effect.

Have used Terminal to run modprobe sg, modprobe sd_mod, modprobe usb_storage and modprobe scsi_mod with no effect noticed or reported.

sg_scan -i in terminal gave,
sg_scan: Error opening /dev/sg0 : Permission denied 
/dev/sg1: scsi2 channel=0 id=0 lun=0 [em] 
    PIONEER   DVD-RW  DVR-217F  1.07 [rmb=1 cmdq=0 pqual=0 pdev=0x5]

lsusb and lspci in Terminal do not list the internal card reader, or anything that might be it.

I have also found 'Getting Started with Ubuntu 12.10', but that has not indicated what to try next.

I have also found vendors with card readers based on the Alcor AU6370 that they advertise as Linux compatible, but I have doubts.

Advise please.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please be more *specific* about what you've tried, what the terminal commands output was, etc. It would be sad if we ask to provide the same information you already got there and likewise for answers with steps you already took. Also, include more hardware information. Include at least the output of `lsusb` and `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(SD Host|MMC|card read|alcor)"` in your question.

Comment: roger@roger-desktop:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(SD Host|MMC|card read|alcor)"
roger@roger-desktop:~$

Comment: The above is a copy of what Terminal showed when I input the above requested 'code'.  To me it seems that it was ignored, or that I have incorrectly input.

Comment: Now that you say it's a USB device, please give the complete output of `lsusb`. It may not be listed with a name you recognize as being a card reader, but the numerical IDs might reveal it. I'm skilled at that. So please post the output of it rather than telling it does not list it.

Comment: roger@roger-desktop:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 050d:705c Belkin Components F5D7050 Wireless G Adapter v4000 [Zydas ZD1211B]
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c045 Logitech, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0d62:0004 Darfon Electronics Corp. Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
roger@roger-desktop:~$

Comment: I would like to be able to add these outputs such that they look like they do in Terminal, but I do not know how.

Comment: Please **edit** your question to include this output. Copy/paste it in, then select it all, and use the "Code sample" formatting button to format it properly. Thanks! Comments are not fit for this. It's Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Comment: It seems indeed not to list any form of card reader. So either one of your internal USB hubs is deactivated or it's not wired up properly. Either way, it sounds like a hardware issue.

Answer (score 1):

The above analysis that it was a hardware problem proved to be correct.  Thank you for your patience with me.

I replaced the original 3.5" multi-card reader with a Pluscom branded one and both SD and SDHC cards are now accessible as intended.  I do not have other types of card to try.  The controller is an Alcor AU6477.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a way to get it to work I recommend trying to get an alternative even though you think it won't work.. But most card readers problems I've read about are related to this but I googled card readers for linux to find you some you could purchase if you don't find a way and couldn't really find anything for you. I recommend to find some commands, google it a bit more, and if that doesn't work then.. :(

Comment: Getting an alternative card reader seems like an admission that the logic of Linux coding is not understood.  If we have the ability to get some internal card readers to work, why can we not get them all working?

Comment: gertvdijk, Please also see this Terminal information,roger@roger-desktop:~$ sg_map -i
Error opening /dev/sg0 : Permission denied
Error opening /dev/sda : Permission denied
/dev/sg0  some error
/dev/sg1  /dev/sr0  PIONEER   DVD-RW  DVR-217F  1.07
roger@roger-desktop:~$